# Trigger after update with value depend on other row with same field and table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've got a table which looks something like this

```
    IDLevel(int)<PK> | StepLevel(int)<PK> | Value(decimal)
    ------------------------------------------------------
    1                      1                 a+(0*100)
    1                      2                 a+(1*100)
    1                      3                 a+(2*100)
    1                      4                 a+(3*100)
    1                      5                 a+(4*100)
    1                      6                 a+(5*100)
    1                      7                 a+(6*100)
    1                      8                 a+(7*100)
    1                      9                 a+(8*100)
    2                      1               ((a+(4*100)+a+(5*100))/2)+(0*150)
    2                      2               ((a+(4*100)+a+(5*100))/2)+(1*150)
    2                      3               ((a+(4*100)+a+(5*100))/2)+(2*150)
    2                      4               ((a+(4*100)+a+(5*100))/2)+(3*150)
    2                      5               ((a+(4*100)+a+(5*100))/2)+(4*150)
    etc
```

how can i make it to update the field value automatically based on first value of StepLevel AND IDLevel fields.

**EDITED**

Increasing the StepLevel will add same specific number into Value field.

Increasing the IDLevel will add some arithmetic operation based on StepLevel value from previous IDLevel (as shown on the example, for IDLevel 2 StepLevel 1 will have Value based on IDLevel 1 (StepLevel4 Value + StepLevel 5 Value)/2

Comment: Whatever you are doing - think of another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use DEFAULT syntax to do that using expression between IDLevel and Step Level
like for new table

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE newtb (IDLevel INT DEFAULT 1, StepLevel INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, VALUE DECIMAL DEFAULT expression);
```

Comment: please check my question, I've edited & explained the clue.
thanks 4 your attention...